# Can a corporate proxy intercept HTTPS traffic if it doesn't control the certificate store?

Tags: tls, web-browser, wifi

I sometimes connect my personal devices through the corporate wifi. But besides that, there's not any corporate software on my system that a proxy could use, and Firefox's certificate store is the original one that came with it and receives updates directly from Mozilla.

Does this mean I can trust HTTPS traffic while connecting to the corporate wifi? I don't see any weird mitm certs when I view the details of a connection through Firefox.

Is the original server's private key absolutely needed to fake the cert properties window? Or could the proxy simulate a pristine connection?

I assume it can't, given that this involves robbing the private key somehow by a malicious party, or having a powerful enough quantum computer, heheh.

Comment: The answer below is correct. To add to your Q 'Is the original server's private key absolutely needed to fake the cert properties window? Or could the proxy simulate a pristine connection?' - No you cannot spoof the original private key as your company would have no way of knowing what it was. They only have the public key, and if it was easy to calculate the private key from that then it would be game over for everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general no they can't. If they could then your ISP (and anyone else in the middle) could intercept your HTTPS traffic making it entirely pointless.

They can intercept the traffic but your device should detect the invalid cert and notify you. In theory a corporate with their own CA could MitM you seeing as you would likely have their root cert in your device. But this would risk their CA trust being revoked.

You also need to be careful if ever asked to install corporate provided software on personal devices.